# conversion error from csv to javaRDD

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I don't know why I keep getting the noSuchMethodError for storing csv data in JavaRDD. I have the following class defined, whose instance will be a record in the csv file.

```
public class Historical_Data_Record implements Serializable {
    String tripduration;
    String starttime;
    String stoptime;
    String start_station_id;
    String start_station_name;
    long start_station_latitude;
    long start_station_longitude;
    String stop_station_id;
    String stop_station_name;
    long stop_station_latitude;
    long stop_station_longitude;
    String bikeid;
    String usertype;
    String birth_year;
    int gender; 
    // if 1, male, if 0, female
}
```

then I have the following code that creates Historical_Data_Record object by reading the data from the csv and store in JavaRDD.

```
public static final JavaRDD<Historical_Data_Record> get_Historical_Data(JavaSparkContext sc, String filename){
    // get the data using the configuration parameters 
    final JavaRDD<Historical_Data_Record> rdd_records = sc.textFile(filename).map(
        new Function<String, Historical_Data_Record>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Historical_Data_Record call(String line) throws Exception {
                String[] fields = line.split(",");

                Historical_Data_Record sd = new Historical_Data_Record();           
                sd.tripduration = fields[0];
                sd.starttime = fields[1];
                sd.stoptime = fields[2];
                sd.start_station_id = fields[3];
                sd.start_station_name = fields[4];
                sd.start_station_latitude = Long.valueOf(fields[5]).longValue();
                sd.start_station_longitude = Long.valueOf(fields[6]).longValue();
                sd.stop_station_id = fields[7]; 
                sd.stop_station_name = fields[8];
                sd.stop_station_latitude = Long.valueOf(fields[9]).longValue();
                sd.stop_station_longitude = Long.valueOf(fields[10]).longValue();
                sd.bikeid = fields[11];
                sd.usertype = fields[12];
                sd.birth_year = fields[13];
                sd.gender = Integer.parseInt(fields[14]);
                return sd;
    }});

    return rdd_records;

}
```

But when I run the code below,

```
    JavaRDD<Historical_Data_Record> aData = Spark.get_Historical_Data(sc, filename);
```

where sc is the SparkContext and filename is just the string containing the path to the file. The error is as follows:

```
2014-11-03 11:04:42.959 java[5856:1b03] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
14/11/03 11:04:43 WARN storage.BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_0 failed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.hash.HashFunction.hashInt(I)Lcom/google/common/hash/HashCode;
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.OpenHashSet.org$apache$spark$util$collection$OpenHashSet$$hashcode(OpenHashSet.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.OpenHashSet$mcI$sp.getPos$mcI$sp(OpenHashSet.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.OpenHashSet$mcI$sp.contains$mcI$sp(OpenHashSet.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$$anonfun$visitArray$2.apply$mcVI$sp(SizeEstimator.scala:214)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitArray(SizeEstimator.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.visitSingleObject(SizeEstimator.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.org$apache$spark$util$SizeEstimator$$estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator$.estimate(SizeEstimator.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putValues(MemoryStore.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.putValues(MemoryStore.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.put(BlockManager.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:812)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcast.<init>(HttpBroadcast.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(HttpBroadcastFactory.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(HttpBroadcastFactory.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:776)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.hadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.textFile(JavaSparkContext.scala:164)
    at com.big_data.citibike_project.Spark.get_Historical_Data(Spark.java:19)
    at com.big_data.citibike_project.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

At first, I thought this may be because there is the header, so I removed it. But again, it was the same error. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: actually, I just executed textFile("csv_file"), and it gave me the same error. anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses pretty old guava version (14.0.1) and look like one of your dependencies bring newer incompatible version. Try to fix guava version to version of spark.

Also this one may be interested - http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Is-Spark-1-1-0-incompatible-with-Hive-td17364.html